# Param attribute usage in @Result Annotation

Tags: java, json, struts2, struts2-convention-plugin

How to specify the variables to be converted to JSON in @Result Annotation?

Now it is converting all variables with getters to JSON String.

How to use params attribute in @Result?

```
@Action(value = "save", results = { @Result(name = "success", type = "json") })
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think this should work:

```
@Result(type = "json", params = {
            "includeProperties",
            "var1,var2"
        })
```